# BOINC [error] State file error: missing file <wu_name>_0_1

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to set up a BOINC server to do some serious crunching. I successfully set up the project, and wrote my code using the "wrapper" setup. However I am not able to get the app to process data on the clients.

I was using the [instructions from the BOINC wiki](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/WrapperApp) as a guide

I set up my app folder, added the wrapper and the worker as described, set up my XML file and templates, and ran make_work. All seemed good, but when my client connected to the project, it downloaded everything except the actual file I passed to make_work. The log said:

`[error] State file error: missing file <wu_name>_0_1`

where `<wu_name>` was, obviously, the name of the workunit file passed to make_work.

I've double-checked everything and can't find the problem. ANy ideas as to where I would start looking?

Here's my wu template:

```
<file_info>
<number>0</number>
</file_info>
<workunit>
<file_ref>
<file_number>0</file_number>
<open_name>in</open_name>
<copy_file/>
</file_ref>
<min_quorum>1</min_quorum>
<target_nresults>1</target_nresults>
</workunit>
```

And my wu result template

```
<file_info>
<name><OUTFILE_0/></name>
<generated_locally/>
<upload_when_present/>
<max_nbytes>10000</max_nbytes>
<url><UPLOAD_URL/></url>
</file_info>
<result>
<file_ref>
<file_name><OUTFILE_0/></file_name>
<open_name>out</open_name>
</file_ref>
</result>
```

And my job.xml should it matter:

```
<job_desc>
<task>
<application>test7zpwd</application>
<stdin_filename>stdin</stdin_filename>
<stdout_filename>stdout</stdout_filename>
<command_line></command_line>
</task>
</job_desc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the BOINC user mail lists here: http://boinc.berkeley.edu/email_lists.php would be your best bet.  Since this application is so specific, it is tough to get an expert on that particular beast here on serverfault.

Comment: Hey. This question has been pretty much dead... I asked it first over there and nobody helped me. But since you were the only person to answer here, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for trying!